# Synchronous vs Asynchronous logic - SR-Flipflop

Tags: logic, vhdl, fpga, flip-flop, digital-design

I have came across a logical design where I have some questions. The first questions is whether there are two separate SR flip-flops in this design? The second question is whether a clock normally is used to propagate the inputs through the design or if this can be called combinatorial? Because I have difficulty understanding how many clock cycles it will take to propagate an input to the output. If I understand it correctly, it will first take a clock cycle to propagate through the first part of the design (the first flip-flop?) and then the second clock cycle will propagate the new inputs to the second part of the design (second flip-flop?).

[image: logical design]

I am trying to implement this design in VHDL, but not entirely sure if I just can do something like this:

```
entity logic_design is
  port(
    R     : in std_logic;
    S1    : in std_logic;
    R1    : in std_logic;
    A     : in std_logic;

    Q     : out std_logic;
    Q_bar : out std_logic
  );
end logic_design;

architecture Behavioral of logic_design is

signal sig_Q1_out     : std_logic;
signal sig_Q1_bar_out : std_logic;
signal sig_Q2_out     : std_logic;
signal sig_Q2_bar_out : std_logic;

begin

process(S1, R1)
begin

   sig_Q1_out     <= S1 nand sig_Q1_bar_out;
   sig_Q1_bar_out <= R1 nand sig_Q1_out;

   sig_Q2_out     <= sig_Q1_out nor sig_Q2_bar_out;
   sig_Q2_bar_out <= (sig_Q2_out nor A) nor R;

end process;

Q     <= signal_Q2_out;
Q_bar <= signal_Q2_bar_out;
```

Also, are there any examples where such design is applied. I have read that this is quite common for denouncing when using switches and buttons without properly understanding how this can help to avoid bouncing.

Comment: Your diagram and VHDL code don't match. ***...I have difficulty understanding how many clock cycles it will take to propagate an input to the output.*** There is no discernible clock in either. Your question is unclear. Have you considered simulating? You're not showing us how it is used.

Comment: 2 downvotes?! Why? This is a perfectly reasonable question on combinatorial logic, and shows some research effort, and is *far* better than the vast majority of VHDL or Verilog questions on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently your design is combinatorial because you don't have any clock in it nor a shift register flip-flop. This means if you change the inputs, the outputs will update directly, there may be a delay but it is not taken in account during a simulation.

If you want your design to be sequential you need to add registers (aka. D Flip Flop) to store temporary results. The behavior of a DFF is to store the input and pass it as an output on a rising edge clock.

[image: D Flip Flop behavior]

Considering the D is the input and Q is the output you see that you need to wait the next rising edge of the clock to propagate the input signal to the output or in a combinatorial design. This is how you make a circuit synchronous and create pipelines by the way.

I advice you to try to implement a D Flip Flop by yourself with the kind of behavior and add one before each input and one after each output. In order to obtain this design :
[image: Synchronous circuit principle]

Then you should simulate it and you'll see that your outputs change on a rising edge clock only, also you will see you only have one clock cycle between the change of the input and the update of the output. Also this is the principle on how create a synchronous circuit.

If you want more cycles (in order to up the clock frequency for example) you have to split your design in two combinatorial design and add a DFF between them. Between Q1 and S2 for example. If you do so the first clock cycle will compute Q1 from your inputs and store it in the middle DFF and the second clock cycle will compute the outputs from Q1.

I think you should look for some books or lessons that explain how to make such designs, it's a necessary base if you want to make some digital circuit.

Answer (score 1):

There are two cascaded SR *latches* in the design, not flip-flops. Both of them are classical cross-coupled NAND latches (you can see this if you De-Morganise the second latch).

This is a completely combinatorial circuit; there are no clocks, and you have to think in terms of combinatorial, not clocked/sequential logic.

What it actually does, though, I'm not sure. In general, S1 and R1 are active-low control inputs, and Q2 is an active-low output. S1 'sets' (and forces) Q2 (to 0), but the reset (to 1) is more complicated - you have to release R1, and then set A or R2, and it's not obvious what the point of that is. It's presumably part of a bigger circuit - possibly a flip-flop implementation of some sort (note that everything you think of as 'clocked' logic is actually fundamentally an asynchronous combinatorial circuit, like this one). A single SR latch can be used for debouncing, but this is for board-level design - you wouldn't do that in a chip (you would instead make everything clocked).

Your VHDL is a good start, but you need A and R2 in the sensitivity list. With your current logic, they're actually *sampled* when S1 or R1 changes (so you've adding two sampling circuits, ie. flip-flops). I would break it into two processes, where the first is sensitive to S1 and R1, and the second is sensitive to Q1, A, R2.

You could potentially synthesise this circuit into an FPGA, but you need to be careful with timing, or it won't work.